# Busca com acentos e sem acentos Postgresql

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Olá,

estou tentando fazer uma busca através de um campo no aplicativo, ele procura a palavra no banco de dados(postgres), porem, tem muito produto cadastrado no banco, com e sem acento, por exemplo, tem café e cafe cadastrado..

procurei uma solução para ele ignorar os acentos e achei essa solução:

```
"function('TRANSLATE'," + part + ",'ÀÁÃãáàÉÈéèÍíÓóÒòÕõÚúÇç','AAAaaaEEeeIiOoOoOoUuCc')";
```

onde part é a variavel que contem a palavra que o usuario pesquisou.

só que tem um problema, ele me resolveu o seguinte: Agora quando eu escrevo cafe(sem acento) ele me retorna tudo, até mesmo com acento, OK
Mas quando eu pesquiso café(com acento) ele nao me retorna nada, nem com e nem sem acento.

Alguem tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

À partir da versão 9.3 você tem o módulo [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/unaccent.html)

Para instalar um módulo no PostgreSQL, proceda assim:

1- Verifique se o módulo está disponível

```
Select * from pg_available_extensions();
```

2- No caso, o módulo `unaccent` é distribuído com o PostgreSQL, então adicione:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
```

Agora você é capaz de executar a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT unaccent('café');
```

Fiz um exemplo aqui (O SQLFiddle não permite adicionar extensões)

```
create table produtos (
    id serial primary key,
    nome varchar(40) NOT NULL
);

insert into produtos (nome) values ('Café'),('Cafe sem acento'),('Pão'),('Leite'),('Açucar'),('Feijão'),('Abóbora');

--Tra
Select id, nome
from produtos
where lower(unaccent(nome)) like '%pa%';-- retorna "Pão"


Select id, nome
from produtos
where unaccent(nome) like '%e%';-- retorna "Café", "Cafe sem acento","Leite","Feijão"


Select id, nome
from produtos
where unaccent(nome) like '%ao%';-- retorna "Pão","Feijão"
```

No seu caso, aplique a função tanto no campo como no critério

```
Select id, nome
from produtos
where lower(unaccent(nome)) like '%'|| unaccent('café') || '%';-- retorna "Café","Cafe sem acento"
```

Comment: Fazendo uso dessas funções na pesquisa ele continuará a usar os indices se tiver?